# SQL query to find multiple wives

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a database containing a table named "Couple" which representing data couples.

This Table contains the following fields: `CoupleId, WifeId, HusbandId, startDate, Enddate` 
where `startdate` represent the date in which marriage start, and `enddate` represent the date in which marriage end.

The  `HusbandId` and `WifeId` are foreign keys from another table called `Person` where additional information for each person stored.

I need a query that returns the information of women who are married to two man or more at the same time (synchronized wife).

for example , a female with #1 married to male with #2 form 1-1-2012 to 1-5-2012 (dd-mm-yyyy) , and this female (with #1) married to male with #3 from 1-3-2012 to 1-4-2012 ,, this is called a synchronized marriage for female #1

Comment: Pleas explain what queries you have [already tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Sounds like homework :-)  Show us what you've tried!

Comment: Man! If only had synchronized wife...

Comment: Yes this is homework :) 
I have a query that return the information of women who are married more than one time, but i cannot figure out who have a synchronized marriage ( I mean married to two man or more at same time)

Comment: @Daniel you want to share your wife with another man???

Comment: Please state the database system you are using. SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: @ErikE I'm using Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT A.WifeID
FROM
   dbo.Couple A
   INNER JOIN dbo.Couple B
      ON A.WifeID = B.WifeID
      AND A.HusbandID <> B.HusbandID -- or A.CoupleID > B.CoupleID
      AND A.StartDate < B.EndDate
      AND A.EndDate > B.StartDate;
```

To actually figure out how many concurrent relationships there are for each person, with FromDate and ToDate ranges, is a much more involved query.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I have another question , in my problem there is a condition that a male allow to married upto 4 female at same time , how to figure out if any man married to 5 or more at same time

Comment: Please ask a new question. Link me here. But I'll only help if you try on your own and show what you've tried.

Comment: You join on husband id only for duplicate removal coming from the self join, right?

Comment: Yes @sorencito otherwise every husband would be his own cuckold.

Comment: Probably it isn't an interesting scenario, but you remove those husbands who were betrayed a second time by their wifes. I'd stick to my solution and count the wifeids, but dividing the result by 2. Then you'd have the number of relationships at a time. This would also be a solution to the second part of the homework, wouldn't it?

Comment: But your answer is incorrect... how can you "stick to your solution"?

Comment: I mean the general idea of using count and a having clause, together with your inner join to finally make it consider the marriage-boundaries. I'll edit my solution once I have access to a real computer. Hold on. This'll be after XMas...

Comment: I think you will find it isn't as simple as that. For >= 3 you will get more records than you expect. Consider a marriage to 3 men, then divorce from one, then later marry another for a total of 3 again. How will you count that... 4? But not 4 at a time!

Comment: @ErikE when I tryout this Query (Without DISTINCT) on a table which has a wife with 3 synchronized marriage, it return 6 result why?

Comment: Because each one matches with 2 others. For each marriage (3) it overlaps with 2 others = 6.

Comment: I have reformulated my answer considering the start and end dates. The main problem with Eriks query is that it relies upon the husbandid. This is 100% correct for the given scenario, but does not scale with the requirements. Please review my new answer.

Comment: @ErikE The new query copes with all the scenarios you've mentioned, doesn't it?

Comment: @MGCR7 Please post a new question so I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Rather use a correlated subquery than a self join. It's easier to read and understand, because it frees the reader from thinking about duplicates in a self join.

```
SELECT COUNT(A.CoupleId) "no of conflicting relationships", A.WifeId
FROM
  COUPLE A
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT AA.WifeId
    FROM COUPLE AA
    WHERE 
    A.WifeId = AA.WifeId AND -- same wife, but ...
    A.CoupleId <> AA.CoupleId AND -- another couple (independent of husband)
    A.StartDate < AA.EndDate AND
    A.EndDate > AA.StartDate
)
Group By A.WifeId
Having COUNT(A.CoupleId) > 1 -- optional for the given scenario, as the result will only contain records > 1
```

Comment: You need to take the dates into account.

Comment: No it didn't. All the requirements are available in the first post--"at the same time".

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Didn't read carefully enough and relied on another wrong answer which now isn't there anymore. Mea culpa.

Comment: Revised answer and reformulated query, dropped the older query completely as it was plain wrong.

Comment: This is still not going to work. But I take your point about `CoupleId`--it is an equally valid way to count or join. More later when I have time.

Comment: @ErikE Ah, I've got your point. Yes, the query counts also those couples that were not concurrent at the same time.

Comment: I fear the only way is using either a triple self join in my exists clause or a 4x self join.

Comment: What if there are 7 concurrent spouses, then 6, then 7 again? How will you display it? [Here's my query that can answer exactly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d29df/1) any details you could want. With only slight modification (actually simpler) it can show the count each time a spouse changes rather than the consistent # of concurrent spouses (see HusbandID 35 with 3 rows as is, but 6 different relationships).

Comment: Kewl :-)  I'll have a closer look tomorrow!

Comment: Hats off! That's far from where I would have gone in SQL...really nice. Difficult homework, by the way :-) I'll change my answer to "conflicting" as "concurrent" is misleading. At least it's correct for the question given.

Comment: Thanks! Remember to tag if someone else has commented and the person you're replying to is not the owner of the thing commented on. As "homework" goes... this is one of the most difficult things one can try to do! I am a professional with 10 years under my belt and it was not exactly difficult but not exactly something I could toss off  in my sleep. I wonder what the instructor expects.

Comment: @ErikE I think the instructor expected the pupil to come up with a 4x self join which would at least work for the 4-husband-story (although this'd be a quite ugly query). I ran my query against your data and it gives the expected results. Wife 1 never had a completely legal relationship, all 7 do conflict at some point. Same is true for Wife 9, who had 4 illegal relationships. Wife 16 only had one conflict (involving two relationships of course) with Husband 25 and 26. The output is the same as for your solution, just with the number of conflicting relationships :-) Not useful, but correct ;-)

Comment: (In this new fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/153bf/1), see WifeID 41. You correctly count this as 3 conflicting relationships. But when it comes to "at the same time" the only correct answer is 2. Given your persistence and your obvious SQL skill, I wish I could upvote your answer but... alas, alack, I can't, because it doesn't actually answer the question. I hope you take it philosophically. :)

Comment: @ErikE Checkmate. It is not at the same time, but it behaves just as I explained. This does not cover the extended question, alright.  By when it comes to the original question, my answer is correct. And I still find it easier to read than the self join with a distinct clause :-)

Comment: If it's just "married to two or more at the same time" then in fact I can't argue with the correctness of your answer--you definitely show *that*.

Answer (score 0):

do a self join on table as :

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.WifeID
FROM Couple c1
   INNER JOIN Couple c2 ON c1.WifeID = c2.WifeID
   AND c1.HusbandID <> c2.HusbandID
   AND c1.StartDate < c2.EndDate
   AND c2.StartDate < c1.EndDate;
```

but for huge data the execution time will be more...

Answer (score -1):

select count(wifeid),wifeid
from couple
where enddate > GETDATE() or enddate is null

Comment: Incorrect... getdate() is not needed. Your aggregate requires a group by clause...

Comment: I did ran this code in SQL 2005 and it worked perfectly, I accept the get date is not required.

Comment: First, think about it. When does it make sense to put an aggregate on a column that is included in the select list outside of an aggregate? Something like **almost never**. Second, the query, which I doubt even runs, won't even come close to producing a right answer.

Comment: ErikE is right, you're statement doesn't even run. Even when adding the required group by clause, it won't produce the desired result.